# Invalid calling object in IE at the start of a for loop

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a search function that grabs some 1700 items from an XML list and will search through them by the user's query.  Beyond that the user can further filter their results by selecting various filters.

It works flawlessly in Chrome but when testing in IE, anytime I click a filter I get an error "invalid calling object" which references the function `sortList()` specifically the line  `for(var i=0; i < loadedList.length; i++)` as shown in more detail below.

Again, Chrome has no problem with this, its a total IE thing.  Setting watches in Chrome, `loadedList` is an HTMLCollection and can have a `.length` method applied but for some reason in IE this does not work.

This script is fairly lengthy but I've tried to include the relevant functions below.

So mapping this out conceptually:

```
    var results = [];
    var loadedList;
    window.onLoad = loadList();

    // actual function 
    function loadList() {

        var items = new XMLHttpRequest();
        items.onreadystatechange = function() {
            //puts all the xml into the loadedList variable
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
                loadedList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("itm");
                sortList();
            }
        };
        items.open("GET", "item-list-file.xml", true);
        items.send();

    };


    function sortList() {

        for (var i = 0; i < loadedList.length; i++) {

            for (var j = 0; j < loadedList.length; j++) {

                if (boxed[j].checked && boxed[j].id.substr(0, 3) == getElement("category", i).toLowerCase().substring(0, 3)) {

                    // getElement is just a function with a catch statement to handle any missing info on the xml list


                    //pushes any relevant results into results array
                    results.push("<li>" + getElement("title", i) + "</li>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

That's the gist of what happens when the page loads.  There is a `search()` function which just grab's the user's query and passes it to a `returnSearch()` function.  There are no problems with any of that.
The problem arises after the user has searched once and wants to narrow the search by selecting one or more filters.
There is a function, `updateURL()`, which both updates the `window.location.href` (so we can link to the search with specific filters already selected), and then runs `sortList()` again.

```
  function updateURL(searchType) {

    //this resents the results array so that
    results = [];

    //resorts results based on new criteria
    sortList();

   //runs search again so that the filters are applied asynchronously 
    search();


  };
```

Comment: Your `window.onload` assignment is wrong. It should be `window.onload = loadList;` if you really want to wait for the page to be loaded; otherwise just call `loadList()`.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to format and indent your code in a consistent, readable way. (It's a good idea when not asking for help, too.) I've tried to do that for you, but there's an extra `};` at the end...

Comment: Sorry @T.J.Crowder I was going in to edit but I see you already did.

Comment: What is `boxed`? It seems to come out of nowhere in the code. Separately: Despite what IE seems to be telling you, I very much doubt the error is when you're looking at `length`. But fortunately, IE11 does have a built-in JavaScript debugger, so your best bet is probably to use that debugger and step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: boxed just keeps track of which filters are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could tell for some reason IE did not like having the variable `loadedList` declared outside of the `loadList()` function.  I don't know why but after the items initially loaded there would always be problems with `loadedList` whenever `sortList()` was called again.

I ended up removing the function `loadList()` and just having the xml in the body (not in a function).

```
        var items = new XMLHttpRequest();
        items.onreadystatechange = function() {
            //puts all the xml into the loadedList variable
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var xmlDoc = this.responseXML;
                loadedList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("itm");
                sortList();
            }
        };
        items.open("GET", "item-list-file.xml", true);
        items.send();



    function sortList() {
```

Still not sure what IE's issue with this was but it works now.